# Synchronizing two buttons in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, button, onclick

I have two buttons, for styling purposes to get correct textalign, but I want them to behave as one button (e.g. user should think it is one button, so if one is pressed then the default animation for both pops up).

How do I implement this?

Comment: you can use broadcast or listener to implement

Answer (score 0):

Try handle `setOnTouchListener` for each button

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // change both button1 and button2 color when press
            button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            // change both button1 and button2 color when release
            button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   // do same like button1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I had, but I'm trying to mimick the default functionality of an android button, is there a way to set button1 and button2 to activate their native onTouch instead of @override?